Some questions regarding Acoustic wave reflection
I'm new to this subject so bear with me. I have some fundamental question regarding wave reflection/transmission.
Lets say I have a metal cable connected to an end support (pillar) and waves are induced in that cable. My goal is to get the maximum amount of reflection of this setup.
From what I gathered, the reflected wave amplitude is given by the reflection coefficient, and highest reflection occurs when the acoustic impedances between the pillar and the cable are most different.
My question is, how does the geometry of the end support play a role?
I mean, what would be the reflection coefficient and how can I calculate it if L2 is really small or comparable to the wavelengths λ0,λ1... (in which case lets assume I have another material 3).
Also, how does the reflection coefficient changes if I put constraints on the pillar, meaning, I put tension its various surfaces, or compress them.
If someone can point me to a book/article/paper that covers this topic thoroughly
 please let me know!

Could you please define all the variables that you present? What is $\rho$, $\lambda$, $L$ and $c$? What kind of waves are we talking about, mechanical, electromagnetic? What parameters can you change and what are the boundary conditions (how are the interfaces connected)?

Short Answer: Its complicated, and a full description would require an intense modeling effort.
Longer Answer:
Transverse waves (note I am ignoring compressional waves; I am not sure which you are interested in) in the cable (assumed to be a taut string; valid if the tension forces are much larger than any elastic bending force in the cable) are strongly dependent on the boundary conditions.  The relevant boundary conditions are on the position of the cable (Dirichlet) and the forces acting on the cable (Neumann) at the boundary.  It is also possible to have situations where both the position and the forces are related, in which case you get a Robin boundary condition.  For a taut string with relatively small waves, the transverse force and position are the only things that matter.
If we care about how the geometry of the end support matters to the waves, then we need to look closely at the model of the end support.  One common approach is to assume some idealized case, such as the end support is approximately rigid, or that the end support is allowed to move in the transverse direction freely.  However, if neither of these cases or similar are valid, then you need to build a full model of the supports.  If the support is really complicated I might recommend building a numerical model.
Some very basic thoughts that might be helpful: First, the bigger, heavier, and stiffer the end support is, the closer the support is to being rigid.  The reflection coefficient for a rigid support is $R=-1$, or all energy is returned with the opposite amplitude of the incoming wave.  Second, if the end support is only stiff in the direction of the cable but able to move around freely in the transverse direction (like a frictionless ring on an immobile post) then the reflection coefficient is $R=1$, or all energy is returned with the same amplitude as the incoming wave.  Some nice animations can be found at this PSU website.
I would need more information about your particular problem if I were to provide more advice.  However, I would recommend the book Fundamentals of Acoustics by Kinsler, Frey, Coppens, and Sanders as a starting point.
